# Refreshing image in Safari on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, caching, safari, browser-cache

I have a Javascript application that needs to refresh some thumbnails frequently.

I have created a timer that will change the `src` attribute of a thumbnail from `someImage.jpg` to `someImage.jpg?0`, then `someImage.jpg?1` and so on. On all desktop browsers this effectively forces a reload of the image, that may - or may not - have changed on the server.

But Safari on iOS (both iPad and iPhone) seems to have a more aggressive caching policy that defeats this strategy. It cheerfully ignores the querystring and does not issue a request for the new asset.

> Is there a way to force all browsers - Safari included - to reload an image?

At worst one thing that should work could be actually changing the URL of the image on the server. Unfortunately this will probably not be under my control, hence I am looking for a Javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue is just that Safari keeps more copies of the downloaded assets, even across page reloads, hence all images named `someImage.jpg?0`, `someImage.jpg?1` and so on, are already in cache. Moving to a random querystring turns out to work.